# Can't enter Programming Mode Atmel Studio

Tags: atmega, atmel, atmel-studio

I have a custom board based on the ATmega328. I want to program it usign Atmel ICE Basic  ISP interface, to make sure that I'm connected to the target I've tried to read it ID, I get the following :
[image]

Since uC isn't programmed before, and I'm using only Atmel Stuff to that I don't know where the  problem is, and how may solve it.
the uC is not wired to anything beside the Pull-up resistor and the and a capacitor as followed :

[image]

any idea how may solve this ?

thanks in advance !

**Update**

uC schematic

[image]

the programer is connected to the SPI

Comment: Atmel ICE does not provide power to the MCU, you have to power it externally. The Vcc pin only serves to read target voltage. How are you powering your Atmega?

Comment: yes I did I've tried 3.3V which I need and 5V too, but didn't made a difference !

Comment: Then I guess its time to post the full schematic and pics of what you assembled. P.s.: I think the DTR cap has to be in the order of 100nF, not 100pF.

Comment: I can do it but  I havn't  soldered anything beside the RESET stuff

Comment: Maybe check if your RST button is in the right orientation and not pulling RST to GND? Can't do much more than guess with the info given.

Comment: is the schematic enough?

Comment: Your capacitor C200 seems to be in the wrong location... The pull up doesn't do anything like this. 
Where in your circuit is the ISP connection located, or do you have wires directly to the microcontroller?

Comment: @Douwe66 yes I have connections directly to the uC

Comment: Your pull-up resistor (R200) for the reset line should be on the other side of the capacitor C200, try that first ;)

Comment: @Douwe66 thanks so much it solves  the issue thanks. please put your comment as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pull-up resistor to your reset pin is connected on the wrong side of the DTR capacitor.

You'd probably want to connect it as below, although I didn't know about DTR until now...

[image]

Comment: no problem, i've experience many similar problems when using avrs. Good luck with your circuit ;)

Comment: Made a quick correction to the circuit, the reset switch also needs to be on the side of the reset pin (if you want to be able to use it).